# Ошибка при импорте sklearn

Tags: python, python-import, sklearn

Ошибка:

```
line 3, in <module> import sklearn ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' Pyton 3.10.2
```

Часть кода:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
```

Дальше код кидать не буду, ибо зачем. Переустановил sklearn, всё равно не работает.

Операционка Win 10 Pro.

Comment: что выдает `pip list`?

Comment: Может у вас несколько версий python установлено?

Comment: У вас несколько окружений питона, вы ставите `sklearn` не в то окружение, в котором этот код запускаете.